# Magento Load Product event observer?

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

The store I am working on has some custom comunity and local modules that handles some custom items in connection with catalog product.

I need an event observer in order to add some additional data to catalog item instance, when it is load.

If this is the right approach, what is the event I should look for?

If you have any other hints, snippets, I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `catalog_product_load_after` event to add additional information to any product like this.

config.xml

```
<catalog_product_load_after>
        <observers>
            <MagentoDiary_FirstModule_Model_Observer>
                <class>MagentoDiary_FirstModule_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>updateProductName</method>
           </MagentoDiary_FirstModule_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>
```

Observer.php looks like this

```
class MagentoDiary_FirstModule_Model_Observer{

    public function updateProductName(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $product = $observer->getData('product');
        $product->setName($product->getName().' Coooool !');
    }
}
```

Comment: Amit, I belive that the event you suggested is deprecated.. Take a look here: http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Comment: This event is not depricated toll 1.7.x version, If you want to change in frontend then use in <frontend> tag else you can use it in global or <adminhtml>.

Comment: @Michael There are some events that my cheat sheet will miss. There are a whole bunch of events that are fired using the `$this->_eventPrefix` instance variable, such as `_load_after`, `_save_before`, etc.

Comment: Exactly @Nick If you want to see all event on any page load the use this method Mage::dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array()) and log the $name.